# How to identify the important order of each note in inversions?

Tags: theory, chords

Is A C E G with a root on E an Am7 or a CM6 inversion?

In this case why can A be the most important note or just a tension I could skip at the same time?

How should I identify the quality of a chord when the bass isn't the fundamental and things like this happen?

Comment: See also: [C major 6th chord and A minor 7th chord: same notes but different quality, why?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23473/70803).